# How to get the current Linux process ID from the command line a in shell-agnostic, language-agnostic way

Tags: python, linux, shell, command-line, fabric

How does one get their current process ID (pid) from the Linux command line in a shell-agnostic, language-agnostic way?

[`pidof(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof) appears to have no option to get the calling process' `pid`.  Bash, of course, has `$$` - but for my generic usage, I can't rely on a shell (Bash or otherwise).  And in some cases, I can't write a script or compilable program, so Bash / Python / C / C++ (etc.) will not work.

Here's a specific use case: I want to get the `pid` of the running, [Python-Fabric](http://fabfile.org)-based, remote SSH process (where one may want to avoid assuming bash is running), so that among other things I can copy and/or create files and/or directories with unique filenames (as in `mkdir /tmp/mydir.$$`).

If we can solve the Fabric-specific problem, that's helpful - but it doesn't solve my long-term problem.  For general-purpose usage in all future scenarios, I just want a command that returns what `$$` delivers in Bash.

Comment: `cd /proc/self; cut -f 1 -d ' ' stat; cd -` is the only thing that's worked on Ubuntu server 11.04 thus far.  None the other `/proc`-based solutions have worked; they either generate a pid that's not the currently-running process pid, or don't deliver any number.

Looking more and more like it's going to have to be a depend-on-a-shell thing.  Workable, but not optimal in all cases.  Ultimately, in long term, think `pidof` should be updated with something like a `pidof --self` feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great answers + comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8281438/605356) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8281456/605356).  Thx all.  Combining both into one answer, providing two options with tradeoffs in POSIX-shell-required vs no-POSIX-shell-required contexts:

1. POSIX shell available: use [`$$`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8281456/605356)
2. General cmdline: employ [`cut -d ' ' -f 4 /proc/self/stat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8281438/605356)

Example session with both methods (along with other proposed, non-working methods) shown [here](http://pastebin.com/yxiiT9HP).

(Not sure how pertinent/useful it is to be so concerned with being shell independent, but have simply experienced many times the "run system call without shell" constraint that now seek shell-independent options whenever possible.)

Answer (score 67):

From python:

```
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.getpid()
12252
```

Comment: That gives the PID of the python shell! Use this instead: `python3 -c "import os; print(os.getppid())"`

Comment: Well, this doesn't answer the question above, but it does answer the one I came here with (:

Comment: Yeah, I don't really understand why this question is tagged 'python', but I'm glad your comment is here, @Pithikos! ;-)

Answer (score 9):

`$$` isn't bash-specific -- I believe that it's available in all POSIX-compliant shells, which amounts to pretty much every shell that isn't deliberately being weird.

Comment: Thx... but can't rely on ANY shell... bash or any other.

Comment: Any system that can run an SSH server will probably have a POSIX-compliant shell. Any system weird enough to not have one is likely to also lack whatever fallback you choose, as well as other things you're implicitly depending on (like `/tmp` or `mkdir`).

Comment: @duskwuff POSIX-compliant would exclude `csh` and its ilk. The way I understood its question is that the client-side process would be executing some commands on behalf of some user-defined script running in the SSH session – and the only restriction on those scripts would be that they have to be in some sort of Unix shell.

Comment: In Python-Fabric a "require some POSIX shell" dependence may be valid.  In some other circumstances, may not be able to rely on _any_ shell (eg, in some Python system calls... but granted Python has its own api to determine pid).  Alas, if I have to depend on a shell, I have to depend on a shell.  But golly, something like 'pidof --self' would be a lot better than `cd /proc/self; cut -f 1 -d ' ' stat; cd -` (per my comment to main question above), which has not yet been tested for portability across other Linux-es (besides my Ubuntu 11.04).

Comment: Right; my point is simply that `echo $$` is likely be just as portable as the other alternatives presented here, if not more so. (Anything using `/proc`, for instance, will only work on Linux; `$$`, on the other hand, will even work on Windows.)

Answer (score 7):

Hope this is portable enough, it relies on the PPID being the fourth field of `/proc/[pid]/stat`:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 4 /proc/self/stat
```

It assumes a Linux with the right shape of `/proc`, that the layout of `/proc/[pid]/stat` won't be incompatibly different from whatever Debian 6.0.1 has, that `cut` is a separate executable and not a shell builtin, and that cut doesn't spawn subprocesses.

As an alternative, you can get field 6 instead of field 4 to get the PID of the ["session leader"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18166/what-are-session-leaders-in-ps). Interactive shells apparently set themselves to be session leaders, and this id should remain the same across pipes and subshell invocations:

```
$ echo $(echo $( cut -f 6 -d ' ' /proc/self/stat ) )
23755

$ echo $(echo $( cut -f 4 -d ' ' /proc/self/stat ) )
24027

$ echo $$
23755
```

That said, this introduces a dependency on the behaviour of the running shell - it has to set the session id only when it's the one whose PID you actually want. Obviously, this also won't work in scripts if you want the PID of the shell executing the script, and not the interactive one.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work, although `cd /proc/self; cut -f 1 -d ' ' stat; cd -` does:  http://pastebin.com/rQmFikTN

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh Hm, right, at that point /proc/self will point to the *pid* of `readlink`. Luckily the file also contains the *ppid*, I'll amend my answer to a single-command solution.

Comment: Ok, new flavor (`cut -d ' ' -f 4 /proc/self/stat`) does work, and better cmd then mine (no `cd`'s).  http://pastebin.com/yxiiT9HP for example session.  Any idea how portable this is across many linux distro's and older revs (of Linux/kernel)?

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh The [man page for /proc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) mentions that one of the fields in `stat` exists "since Linux 2.1.22", which is an ancient version. I'm interpreting that to mean that the fields not annotated like that have existed before. The version numbers for the `stat` fields listed after that are also increasing, which would imply that new fields are indeed added at the end.

Comment: The fact the layout is tied to Linux kernel version would also imply that it's unlikely to be distro-specific. The only thing remaining is someone doing something weird to `cut` but a Linux will very very likely use the GNU coreutils version.

Answer (score 1):

Fewer characters and guaranteed to work:

```
sh -c 'echo $PPID'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the proc filesystem, then /proc/self is a symlink to the current /proc/$pid.  You could read the pid out of, for instance, the first column of /proc/self/stat.

If you are in python, you could use os.getpid().

Comment: `/proc/self` on my Ubuntu 11.04 system doesn't show pid of running process:  http://pastebin.com/Ggg8BZYV

Comment: when you run: "readlink -f /proc/self | xargs basename"  you are getting the pid of readlink, not the pid of the shell in which you ran readlink.  when you run  "ll -d /proc/self" you are getting 'self' from the ll process.